# How do I get the included elements during include in php?

Tags: php, include

I'd like to get the class/included variables/elements when I included a php file/class, somehow maybe I should try reflection to do that? If so, how?

For instance, I'd have a PHP class called foo.php:

```
<?php
class foo
{
     public function bar()
     {
         return "foobar";
     }
}
?>
```

then, in bar.php, I would like to:

```
<?php
class bar
{
     public function foo()
     {
         $included_resources = include("foo.php"); // Notice, $included_resources is an array
         if (($key = array_search("foo", $included_resources)) != false) // "foo" can be any variable or class name
            return $included_resources[$key]->bar();
     }
}
$helloworld = new bar();
echo $helloworld->foo();
?>
```

Result: a string value of "foobar" will be represented on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, store the declared variables in an array before including a file. Then do the include. Then store the declared variables in another array again. Then simply check the difference:

```
$declared_vars_before = get_defined_vars();
include 'another_file.php';
$declared_vars_after = get_defined_vars();
foreach ($declared_vars_after as $value) {
  if (!in_array($value, $defined_vars_before)) {
    echo $value . '<br>';
  }
}
```

Same with classes, but use get_declared_classes instead of get_defined_vars.